# Finding out the names of symbols

Tags: punctuation, symbols

Is there a comprehensive list on the web where I can find the names of common symbols? Google unfortunately doesn't search on symbols, so it is pretty much useless there.

Specifically, what is `` ` `` called (the symbol to the left of <kbd>1</kbd> on US keyboards)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`` ` `` is the [grave accent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grave_accent), [U+0060](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/60/index.htm).

Resources I can recommend: [Unicode Code Charts](http://www.unicode.org/charts/#symbols), Wikipedia: [Punctuation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punctuation), [Diacritic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diacritic).

Comment: It's also referred to as `backtick`.